# How to detect no data returned in C# LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I am doing a repeated query below, with 'a' and 'b' incrementing ('b' increments to a limit, then reset and 'a' increments). There may be multiple row with given values of 'a' and 'b'.

```
    struct MyData {int mdA; int mydB; }
    ....

    int find_next_a(int a, int b)
    {
      var q = from p in db.pos
        where (p.a >= a && p.b > b) || (p.a > a && p.b > 0)
        orderby p.a, p.b
        select new MyData
        { 
          mdA = p.a, 
          mdB = p.b 
        };

      return q.First().mdA;   // ERROR: InvalidOperationException at end of data
    }
```

The query works until I reach the end of the table. Then I get the exception InvalidOperationException. I can't call q.Count() because I get the same exception.

How can I detect that q has no valid data in it?

[**EDIT**:]
Thanks *Jon Skeet* (and Bojan Skrchevski, Bodrick), I post the solution to above.

```
    int find_next_a(int a, int b)
    {
      var q = from p in db.pos
        where (p.a >= a && p.b > b) || (p.a > a && p.b > 0)
        orderby p.a, p.b
        select new { p.a, p.b };

      var result = q.FirstOrDefault();  // catch running past end of table
      if (result == null)
        return -1; 

      return q.First().a;  // return real data
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `FirstOrDefault` instead:

```
var result = q.FirstOrDefault();
if (result == null)
{
    // Query results were empty
}
```

Note that there's no way of telling between "a real result which is the default value for the element type" and "no results"... it's not a problem here, as all your real results are non-null references, but it's worth being aware of.

EDIT: I hadn't noticed that you were using a custom struct; I'd misread it as an anonymous type. I'd strongly recommend using an anonymous type here instead of a mutable struct. Or, given that you only need `mdA` anyway, you could use:

```
var q = from p in db.pos
        where (p.a >= a && p.b > b) || (p.a > a && p.b > 0)
        orderby p.a, p.b
        select (int?) p.a;

int? result = q.FirstOrDefault();
if (result == null)
{
    // No results - take whatever action
}
else
{
    // Got a result - find the underlying value...
    int a = result.Value;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work with the given example (it doesn't compile coz MyData and null aren't compatible) **BUT** it did point me to the solution. By _not_ using MyData at all, I **CAN** use FirstOrDefault().

Comment: @ahnkle: Urgh - I hadn't noticed `MyData` is a struct. Ick - mutable structs are nasty IMO. Just use an anonymous type.

Comment: Our answers crossed. I am new to LINQ (2nd week) so still rather finding my way.

Comment: @ahnkle: My point is that even without LINQ, `MyData` is nasty - while there is definitely controversy over it, I prefer to avoid using mutable structs entirely. In this case you *could* just make `MyData` immutable.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `First()` use `FirstOrDefault()` and then check for `null` value before using it.

```
var rResult = q.FirstOrDefault();
if(rResult != null)
{
   var something = rResult.mda;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use FirstOrDefault() to avoid the InvalidOperationException.  In the following example, x will be null if q has no elements.  You can then check this and proceed accordingly.

```
var x = q.FirstOrDefault ();

return x == null ? -1 : x.mdA;
```